# Python using a for loop within html mail body

Tags: python, for-loop, win32com

I have the following piece of code. The length of my_header_list and my_msg_list can change so I am looking to replace the following code with a for loop within the html.

```
def send_email(my_header_list, my_msg_list, recipients):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = ";".join([i for i in recipients])
    mail.Subject = 'Summary | ' + str(datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M"))
    mail.Body = html = """\
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <a href="https://www.awebsite.com">ABC</a>
        <br>
        <b>"""+str(my_header_list[0])+ """</b>
        <br>
        """ +"<br/>".join(str(my_msg_list[0]).split("\n"))+ """
        <br>
        <b>""" +str(my_header_list[1])+ """</b>
        <br>
        """ +"<br/>".join(str(my_msg_list[1]).split("\n"))+ """
        <br>
        <b>""" +str(my_header_list[2])+ """</b>
        <br>
        """ +"<br/>".join(str(my_msg_list[2]).split("\n"))+ """
        <br>
        <b>""" +str(my_header_list[3])+ """</b>
        <br>
        """ +"<br/>".join(str(my_msg_list[3]).split("\n"))+ """
        <br>
        <b>""" +str(my_header_list[4])+ """</b>
        <br>
        """ +"<br/>".join(str(my_msg_list[4]).split("\n"))+ """
        <br>
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>
    """
    mail.HTMLBody = (mail.Body)
    mail.Send()
```

Comment: I would start by splitting your html string in three: The start of your html, the middle part (which you will be doing a for loop on to generate what you need) and the end part which never changes. You then concatenate these three string together.

Comment: Try a list instead. Append your lines within a loop. At the end, join it at the end with `"\n".join(mylist).

Comment: I would like the header to be bold and the msg to be in regular text. Is there a way I can do this if I create a common list for headers and msgs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Collect your lines in a list, join at the end.

```
def send_email(my_header_list, my_msg_list, recipients):
    outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = ";".join([i for i in recipients])
    mail.Subject = 'Summary | ' + str(datetime.now().strftime("%m-%d-%Y %H:%M"))

    myhtml = []            

    myhtml.append("<html>")
    myhtml.append("<head></head>")
    myhtml.append("<body>")
    myhtml.append('<a href="https://www.awebsite.com">ABC</a>')

    for line in range(5):
        myhtml.append("<br>")
        myhtml.append("<b>"""+str(my_header_list[line])+ """</b><br>")
        myhtml.append(""" +"<br/>".join(str(my_msg_list[line]).split("\n"))+ """)

    myhtml.append("</p>")
    myhtml.append("</body>")
    myhtml.append("</html>")

    mail.Body = "\n".join(myhtml)
    mail.HTMLBody = (mail.Body)
    mail.Send()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply changed this string as follows

```
html = """\
    <html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
    <a href="https://www.awebsite.com">ABC</a>"""
for index in range(0,4):
    html = html + """<br>
    <b>"""+str(my_header_list[index])+ """</b>
            <br>
            """ +"<br/>".join(str(my_msg_list[index]).split("\n"))+ """
            <br>
        </p>
    </body>
    </html>
    """
```

Comment: That works perfectly. I have some html after the for loop but my script is reading everything after as it is within the for loop, regardless of the indentation. Is there any way I can mark the end of the for loop?

Comment: That will be through indentation only. Whatever you want to add after the end of for loop, just add that at zero space indentation. Let me know, if this does not help you